# Custom Spring Security Chain not being picked up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

We are upgrading our spring boot and security versions of an app from 1.5.9 to 2.1.13 and 4.2 to 5.1.7 respectively and its causing pain.  Previously we were overriding springSecurityFilterChain bean but that is not allowed in boot 2.1 anymore.  I have configured the following classes to create our own security chain with priority before the default security chain.  I set debugger in a variety of places but it is not getting picked up.  Any ideas?

```
public class CustomSecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{
           public CustomSecurityWebAppInitializer(){
                        super();
           }

           @Override
           protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext){
               try {
                   super.insertFilters(servletContext, new CustomSpringSecurityFilterChain());
           } catch (ServletException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
           }
     }
}
```

And here is the actual chain class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class CustomSpringSecurityFilterChain extends FilterChainProxy {

      public CustomSpringSecurityFilterChain() throws ServletException {
            super(createFilterChains());
       }

       @Bean
       private static List<SecurityFilterChain> createFilterChains() throws ServletException {
           List<SecurityFilterChain> filterChainList = new ArrayList<>();
           //do stuff
           return filterChainList;
        }
```

We also have the following class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
        http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';");
}
```

}

The end result is when I try to go to any of the URLs I just get the White Label Error page.  There is no useful error logging however it appears that tomcat threads arent being created as quickly they normally do based on tomcat logs appearing in locations they dont normally appear relative to others.

Answer (score 0):

Within your `SecurityConfig` you have to set the filter properly in the chain of other filres like

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig
  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(
          new YourFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

And a filter can be written likes this

```
public class YourFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // do stuff
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-architecture) also provides a good section about filters

Comment: We have 3 separate filter chains we want to implement and dont want to override configure 3 times and establish an order so I would prefer to figure out how to create additional security filters chains and put them ahead of the default filter chain.